# Are class names objects in python?

Tags: python, django, class

I am learning python and I started reading about Django framework. In examples, here is what I found:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name
```

It is not important what the code does. My question is about function `ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')`. There we are passing a class name to a function.

Why is it allowed? Are class NAMES objects in python?

Comment: No, you are not passing a class name to a function. You are passing *an actual class* to an instantiation of another class.

Comment: If you are wondering why `Person` is passed as a reference, and `Membership` is passed as a string, it's a feature of Django models to allow the class `Membership` to be referenced using a string before the class is actually defined.

Comment: Relevant documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes `classes` are objects in Python. Every entity in python inherits from the base entity `object` and `class` also inherits from `object`.

```
>>> class People:
...     pass
... 
>>> type(People)
<type 'classobj'>
>>> 
>>> isinstance(People, object)
True
```

This is similar as:

```
>>> class Group(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> type(Group)
<type 'type'>
>>> isinstance(Group, object)
True
```

In **Python 3** both `class class_name:` and `class class_name(object):` returns same type:

```
In [1]: class Person:
   ...:     pass
   ...: 
In [2]: Person
Out[2]: __main__.Person
In [3]: class Group(object):
   ...:     pass
   ...: 
In [4]: Group
Out[4]: __main__.Group
```

---

Every thing in Python is an `object`

```
>>> my_list = []
>>> my_list
[]
>>> isinstance(my_list, object)
True
```

Comment: So user defined types (classes) are not inherited from `object` by default?

Comment: @khajvah Yes user defined classes are also `object` in Python.